# Azure Devops Pipeline variables in Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, environment-variables, powershell

I've tried to figure this out and I can't see why my ipaddress is not getting set.

I've checked code samples and they all suggest I am doing everything correct.

`ip` variable defined here:

[image]

This is my powershell script:

```
# Write your PowerShell commands here.

Write-Host "AGENTIPADDRESS variable is set to ($env:AGENTIPADDRESS)"

$ipaddress = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
Write-Host "ipaddress variable is set to ($ipaddress)"
Write-Host "ip pipeline variable to ($ip)"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]$ipaddress"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=env:IP;]$ipaddress"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$env:IP;]$ipaddress"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]$ipaddress"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]333"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]$ipaddress"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP]999"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]888"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]$ipaddress"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]$ipaddress"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP]114"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP;]123"

Write-Host "ip environment variable to ($ip)"
Write-Host "env:IP environment variable to ($env:IP)"

Write-Host "Set environment variable to ($env:AGENTIPADDRESS)"
```

And here is my output:

[image]

Why can't I set & read the `ip` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you can't reference the changed value in the same task.

I created a new Powershell task and just called `Write-Host "env:IP environment variable set to ($env:IP)"` which output the IP address correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Pipeline Variables are handed to PowerShell as environment variables, which means that `$ip` exists only with the script while you want to use `$env:ip` to pick the environment variable value.

**Note** Secret variables are **not** passed automatically: you must add an explicit `env:` in YAML or as arguments in Classic Editor. The latter means that the PowerShell code must have a `param` declaration (e.g. `param($ip)`)and the Task use *Arguments* field (e.g. `-ip $(ip)`).

[image]